# How to I save text from a document into a variable?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to take the text for a document and save it as a variable. I looked in the documentation and found "getText" something I think shall work. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/footnote-section#gettext

I just get a problem when I try using it, because it's not a pre built function it gives the error massage "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getText' of null". So I looked at some more into it and noticed I needed Authorization:
"Scripts that use this method require authorization with one or more of the following scopes:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly

[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents"](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents%22)

So how do I get the required authorization, do I need to do something different or is there another way i could do it?

It's just going to run on some of my docs for fun to se what funny things I am able to do with the program.
(New to programing, now the basics but just trying to see if programing is something for me)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you use `getText` in your script, or `getText()`? It's a function, so it needs the `()`. The error suggests you missed the `()` - in which case the interpreter thinks you are looking for a property called `getText`. Also, the fact that it's looking for this on `null` suggests you may be missing `()` elsewhere, too.

Comment: The bigger issue here is: all of the preceding notes were guesses on my part, because you have not shown us the relevant parts of your code (so I could be completely wrong in those guesses). You can [edit] your question to show us the relevant code you have written.

Comment: Please provide your script and expected output. It is hard to assume as @andrewjames mentioned since you weren't able to provide anything that can help us give you the best answer

Answer (score 0):

Given with this sample document

[image: sample]

You can start with this sample code below.

#### Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var text = body.editAsText();

  Logger.log(text.getText()); // returns all text in document ("Hey, search for me!!! I am <here>!!")
  
  // 1. Regular expression (exec)
  var regExp = new RegExp("<\(.*\)>", "gi"); // "i" is for case insensitive
  var search = regExp.exec(text.getText())[1];
  Logger.log(search); // returns "here"

  // 2. (search)
  Logger.log(text.getText().search(/here/)); // returns the index where the string was found, or -1 if not found
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- `getText` will return the text of the Class Text.
- If you want to get a specific pattern from the document, you need to use Regular expression. I prefer the exec method. See [usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for more details
- For the authorization, you only need to click allow. I assume you are using apps script due to the tag.